# Show that the map $\phi : Z_{rs}\to Z_r\times\ Z_{s}$ defined by $\phi(m\cdot 1)=m(1,1)$ is surjective with $gcd(r,s)=1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

Our goal in our Abstract Algebra class is to show that the ring $<\mathbb{Z}_{rs},+,\cdot>$ is isomorphic to the ring $<\mathbb{Z}_r\times \mathbb{Z_s},+,\cdot >$ where $gcd(r,s)=1$. We have no problem in showing that the map $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_{rs}\to \mathbb{Z}_r\times \mathbb{Z_s}$ defined by $\phi(m\cdot 1)=m(1,1)$ is (1) one-one and (2) satisfies the ring homomorphism property. But a problem arise when showing that the mapping defined is surjective or onto.

To show that $\phi$ is onto we need to show that for any $(m,n)\in \mathbb{Z}_r\times \mathbb{Z_s}$ there must be $x\in \mathbb{Z}_{rs}$ such that $\phi(x)=(m,n)$. But unfortunately we did not know how to find that $x$.

What is that $x$? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know what is the pigeonhole principle? If you do, then think about this: Think about the set $st+n$, where $t$ is varying between $1$ and $r$. Because $\gcd(r,s)=1$, all the multiples will leave different remainders modulo $r$ But because there are $r$ of them, one of them will leave the remainder $m$. Complete the argument.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I am aware of the pigeonhole principle. I am not aware though that that principle may be used to show ontoness of the mapping $\phi$ thanks for your comment will try answer the problem by considering your notes.

Comment: You are welcome.